# How to increment a counter on click?

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<button id="ES" class="select" type="button">Select</button>
<h2>Total Units: <span id="totalselected"></span></h2>
```

and script:

```
var units=0;
document.getElementById('ES').onclick = function() {
    var units=units+2;
    document.getElementById("totalselected").innerHTML = units;
}​;​
```

I want that when the button is clicked, add + 2 to a counter.
It starts off at 0 and is displayed on the webpage.

When the button is clicked, the number jumps to two.
If it is clicked again, the number jumps to four.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the second `var` on `units`

```
var units=0;
    document.getElementById('ES').onclick = function() {
    units=units+2; // here
    document.getElementById("totalselected").innerHTML = units;
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ficoxuka/1/edit)

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work with mine. http://sths.friedpanseller.com/subjects/index.html

Comment: No not really...Maybe a silly answer but: have you enabled Javascript?

Comment: I have javascript enabled in my browser Version 35.0.1916.114 m Chrome

Comment: Tried it on firefox as well. Still can't click. But your demo worked before. Maybe I have like just one typo somewhere in the code, but can't find it :(

Comment: It seems to work when you put it up somewhere. I even tried on a different computer just then, still not working on my website or when opened on local disk. I guess html doesn't really like me today

Comment: Wrong demosite - Put your `<script src=""></script>` to the bottom before the end `</body>` - Tag [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yahawozu/1/edit)

Comment: You welcome.. use console log to fix your errors.. :)

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
var units=units+2;
```

to this:

```
units=units+2;  // remove the keyword var
```

---

As per your post:

*I want that when the button is clicked, add + 2 to a counter. It starts off at 0 and is displayed on the webpage.*

To start your values from `0` you can move your var `unit = unit + 2` at the bottom:

```
var units=0;
document.getElementById('ES').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById("totalselected").innerHTML = units;
   units=units+2;
};
```

Comment: I assume that the downvote was in relation to your original post from before the edit which causes `units` to become global when just removing `var` and that can cause unexpected side-effects. +1 though as your edit is including the declaration again in the outer scope of the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 var c=0;
function test()
{
c=c+2;
document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML=c;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Click" onClick="test()"/>
Count= <p id="cnt""></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use OPs current code. No need to create your own abstraction which cannot be related back to OPs code. There is also no need to move OPs code which was just fine where it was into in-line JavaScript `onClick="test()"`. Also attaching events using in-line JavaScript can cause shudders down one's spine.